# Update CDSView filter with CustomJS for line glyph

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm struggling to figure out how to update the CDS view filter using a custom callback. A test DataFrame is the following:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, CustomJS, CDSView
from bokeh.models.filters import Filter, GroupFilter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
              'Chapter': ['C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','F','F','F','F'],
              'Page':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
              'Line':[91,92,93,94,81,82,83,84,71,72,73,74,51,52,53,54]})
```

The goal is to produce a line graph with two lines representing the different chapters in the different titles, where the x axis would be Page and y axis Line, where the Title is selectable with the Select widget. The following code creates the figure I'm looking for:

```
test1 = test.groupby('Title', sort = False).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient = 'list'))

graph = ColumnDataSource(data = test1[0])
chapterlist = [*set(test1[0]['Chapter'])]

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)

for i in range(len(chapterlist)):
     view=CDSView(source=graph, 
     filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='Chapter', group=chapterlist[i])])
     p.line(
         x='Page',
         y='Line',
         source=graph,
         view=view,
         legend_label = chapterlist[i])
```

Next we can look at the code for the Select widget, callback and showing the graph.

```
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(graph=graph, source= test1.to_dict()), code =
            """
            graph.data = source[cb_obj.value];
            graph.change.emit();
            """)

select.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = column(select, p)
show(layout)
```

The chrome error I get when using the Select is `group filter: group 'C' did not match any values in column 'Chapter'` which is completely understandable as I did not update the GroupFilter in the CustomJS to match the new Chapters in the selected Title. I tried accessing the GroupFilter from both the source and data object but was unsuccessful.

The reason I need to use Views to begin with is because it is necessary to have the select options be "Title", thus I need all the information for the title available at the same time and need to graph lines for both "Chapters".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This came up recently [on the tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9388) and the conclusion is that use of `CDSView` is not compatible with or supported on line glyphs. A future version will explicitly raise a specific exception to note this incompatibility. As on the issue, I would recommend a Scatter, Bar Chart, or Dot Plot, all of which use glyphs that work with a `CDSView`. If you really need to use lines, my best suggestion is to plot all the lines up front using concrete subsets of data, and use the JS callback to toggle their visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Any alternative since then ?